# What’s the meaning of “expand into” in the sentences: The company is hoping to expand into the European market

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

> The company is hoping to **expand into** the European market.

Is it means- wants to make more money from European market..

Comment: Standard dictionary definitions apply.  *Get larger by entering into something (i.e. the European market).*

Comment: Well, they wouldn't be expanding the European market...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Expand into [area]' in the context of a business means that they intend to grow the business to cover a market they currently do not.

It can be used, as in your example, to refer to a market in the sense of a geographical area:

> We hope to expand in the European market.

It can also be used to refer to a new area of business:

> We hope to expand into the home entertainment market.

Answer (score 1):

The company is not currently selling anything in Europe, but would like to.

Fx. Walmart only have shops in USA, but would like to expand into Europe. So they are opening stores in Germany and Italy... (example, no idea where walmart have shops, or want to have shops :))